# Speeding up using itertools

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am trying to solve the Apple and Orange problem in [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/apple-and-orange).

Here is one solution I came up with

```
s,t = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
s,t = [int(s),int(t)]
a,b = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
a,b = [int(a),int(b)]
m,n = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
m,n = [int(m),int(n)]
apple = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))
orange = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))

ap=0
for e in apple:
    d=a+e
    if d>=s and d<=t:
        ap+=1
ora=0
for e in orange:
    d=b+e
    if d>=s and d<=t:
        ora+=1

print ('%d\n%d' %(ap,ora))
```

I wanted to speed this up. So I googled for a way to iterate both lists at the same time and so used `itertools` and this is the solution I came up with

```
s,t = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
s,t = [int(s),int(t)]
a,b = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
a,b = [int(a),int(b)]
m,n = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
m,n = [int(m),int(n)]
apple = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))
orange = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))

ap=ora=0
for i,j in itertools.izip_longest(apple,orange):
    if i is not None:
        d1=a+i
        if d1>=s and d1<=t:
            ap+=1

    if j is not None:
        d2=b+j
        if d2>=s and d2<=t:
            ora+=1

print ('%d\n%d' %(ap,ora))
```

Does this really make the code faster theoretically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.

You have introduced two additional branches that must be tested each time the loop runs

```
if i is not None:

if j is not None:
```

as well as the overhead of creating the generator object and unpacking the tuple. The only possible benefit I see here is possibly reducing the amount of loop *boundary* checks that need to be done but you will have to benchmark it to see if that outweighs the two `if` conditions. That also only has a chance of helping you if the two lists are similar in length.